# Android - Removing an ImageView from a RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, uiimageview

How can I remove an ImageView from a RelativeLayout? For some reason `RelativeLayout.removeView(iv);` doesn't work. I'm creating the ImageView programmatically like this:

`final ImageView iv = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);` But this doesn't work.

I don't want to use `iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);` because this doesn't really remove the image, it just sets the visibility.

Why isn't this working? Is there any alternative?

Comment: add tag while adding imageview in layout and remove with that particular tag from layout

Comment: @DIVA How do I add a tag? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Why  calling `removeView` on `RelativeLayout` doesn't work? BTW, you should use `this` instead of `MainActivity.this` to create a View, because the constructor accepts a `Context`

Comment: @suitianshi This code is inside an OnClickListener, and `this` doesn't work.

Comment: First assign Tag to your view like iv.setTag("tag1"), and then remove the child from layout using tagName.

Comment: Does `setId` do the same? @ManishL

Comment: You should use the setId() when you only want a way to identify that particular View in your code and setTag when you want to pass additional information along with that View.

Comment: @ManishL, so what should the code to remove the view be? `removeView(?)`

Comment: You should try like 
View root = findViewById(R.id.your_relative_layout);
root.removeView(yourViewToRemove);

Comment: @ManishL What about the Tag? What was the tag for if we don't use it?

Comment: Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a code snip below may help you understand how dynamic tag works :

```
   addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                Button buttonRemove = (Button) addView
                        .findViewById(R.id.remove);
                addView.setTag(tag);
                buttonRemove.setTag(tag);
                dynamicLayoutsTags.add(tag);
                Container.addView(addView);
                tag++;
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent())
                        // .removeView(addView);
                        Integer removeTag = (Integer) v.getTag();
                        View deleteView = Container.findViewWithTag(removeTag);
                        Container.removeView(deleteView);
                        dynamicLayoutsTags.remove(removeTag);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```